# Browser window close event is not working in Firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

I'm using the below code to run when browser window is getting closed:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    return inFormOrLink ? "Do you really want to close?" : null; 
})
```

The above code seems working in IE and not in Firefox and Chrome browser.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in Chrome 69: http://jsfiddle.net/am6sxo8w/. Check you've attached the event handler correctly, and also that `inFormOrLink` has the value you expect.

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan, But the message given in return statement is not displayed.

Comment: Im getting "Changes you made may not be saved." instead of "Do you really want to close?"

Comment: That's the only message Chrome will display. There's no way to change that.